# Asp.Net Identity 2 and oAuth server - architecture

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I have general question regarding integration on Identity 2 with oAuth server. I've read a lot of articles, but I still have some misunderstanding of each part.
Let's take for example next structure:

- MVC application - front end application with all pages (some of them open and some of them secured)

  - WEB API2 application - web api application for different apis that **part** of MVC app is using
  - MVC admin application - admin application with admin role permissions

**Each application lives on different domain or sub domain**

The scenario I want to create:
User (regular or admin) logged into the app with regular login or social network login (facebook/google/microsoft/etc.) once he did this he will be able to go to admin application, web api application and pass the authentication **automatically**.

As I understood, MVC app using external cookie or session and Web API uses tokens.

**What is the proper way to create authentication process for the application?**